# How to use authenticated user's identity in fluentd logs?

Tags: fluentd

Based on [fluentd docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/out_forward#how-to-enable-password-authentication), it's possible to authenticate clients. How could the resulting authenticated identity be used in controlling logging behavior. Some goals I'm trying to achieve are:

- Filtering log records so that `user1` can only send records with tags `user1.**`
- Inject user's username into log records

Comment: I know, quite a lot of time passed. However, I wonder whether you got a good solution for this. I pretty much just asked very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70176032/how-to-get-username-in-fluentd-plugin

Comment: @VictorRonin Not really. We eventually switched to vector and used its `http` source. To handle authentication, we used a reverse proxy, and added the resulting labels to the event there.

Answer (score 0):

How about following?

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  tag dummy
  @label @INPUT
</source>

<label @INPUT>
  <filter>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
      username user1
    </record>
  </filter>
  <match>
    @type rewrite_tag_filter
    <rule>
      key username
      pattern /^(.*)/
      tag $1.${tag}
    </rule>
    @label @OUTPUT
  </match>
</label>

<label @OUTPUT>
  <match>
    @type forward
    <security>
      self_hostname output.testing.local
      shared_key    secure_communication_is_awesome
    </security>
    <server>
      host 127.0.0.1
      port 24224
      username user1
      password yes_this_is_user1
    </server>
  </match>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I can understand how to apply it in a multi-user environment. Let's say there's a `user2` as well. How do I distinguish `user1` records from `user2` records?

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish records by username?

Comment: Because I want to control user's access. I'm going to aggregate logs of different users, and I'd like to store each user's logs separately.

Comment: Where are users from? An application, a hostname, or something?